# Enable debug logs for Endeca forge and dgidx

Tags: endeca, endeca-workbench

Could anybody please guide me on how to enable debug log for forge and dgidx on endeca?

Thanks in advance.

Mohan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Forge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/ForgeGuide.pdf#page=118)** and **[Dgidx](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/IAPAdmin/toc.htm#Dgidx%20flags)** are simply ***Spring beans*** configuration in Endeca (in a file called `DataIngest.xml`).

---

1. **Fire up** your favorite editor and open `<Your-Endeca-App>/config/script/DataIngest.xml`
2. **Search** for the `<forge>` tag
3. In the `<args>` section, **change** the `<arg>-vi</arg>` to `<arg>-vd</arg>` (`vi` stands for "verbose INFO" and `vd` stands for "verbose DEBUG")
4. **Search** for the `<dgidx>` tag
5. **Ensure** `<arg>-v</arg>` is present in the `<args>` section

Comment: Thanks KrishPrabakar.